# NetBeans Java project folder vs. project location

Tags: java, netbeans

I am new to Java and am a little bit confused about how NetBeans manages directory structure. I understand there are structure with main `project name directory`, then `src`, `build`, `dist`, etc.

But what I don't understand is **why NetBeans creates two-level directory in my case below:**

[image]

What's the difference between directories **`project`** and **`myapp`**?

Folder `project` contains `myapp` only and `myapp` contains `src`, `dist`, `build`, etc. Another picture:

[image]

What is directories **`project`** and **`myapp`** for? What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

The project location is a location in which you can store *lots of different projects*. Each will have its own project folder.

Comment: "project location" ... store "lots of diff. projects" - so 1 project can store many projects? am I right?

Comment: No,a single project location is for particularly that single project. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `project` directory is just a place where you've custom-specified the netbeans projects storage.

But, the sub-directory `myapp` is simply one of the project name of your NetBeans projects which is to be stored inside the parent NetBeans projects directory **`(D:\dev\java\project)`** here.

There can be similar several projects which will by default get stored under this `(D:\dev\java\project)` --- NetBeans Projects directory like some :-

```
(D:\dev\java\project\myapp2)

(D:\dev\java\project\myapp3)
```